# Adding NSExceptionDomains in Runtime

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios9

I've successfully added `NSAppTransportSecurity > NSExceptionDomains` in `Info.plist` file like:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<false/>
<key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
<dict>
    <key><!-- your_remote_server.com / localhost --></key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
<!-- add more domain here -->
</dict>
```

But there is a problem, we have this providers where we get rss feeds and displayed in the app and `NSAppTransportSecurity` is blocking them. I want to add the current active providers in the `NSExceptionDomains` dynamically and remove those inactive.

I know that it is not okay to modify the `Info.plist` in runtime but i don't have a choice.

Anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: It's not that it isn't OK to modify the Info.plist, it's that you can't. It's read-only. You can't do what you want other than specify the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` key.

Comment: @rmaddy, you mean i don't have a choice but to add them one by one manually? how can we change the provider remotely then? is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: The Info.plist can't be changed other than by submitting an app update.

Comment: @rmaddy, change the providers every update, that's what i'm trying to avoid. i guess we really don't have a choice then? hmm.. hope apple will have some update for this or probably support at least two Info.plist file (one is editable)

Answer (score 0):

I got into the same crossroad there and the solution I got was instead of communicating my application directly to the dynamic remote server and getting its response, I add my server in the middle, which had the task to be the middle man between the application and the dynamic remote server. This way you just have to add your own server to the `NSExceptionDomains` Info.plist, which, in my case, was already added. Here is the php script I added to my own remote server which was acting as a middle man between my application and the users' remote server:

```
<?php
   echo (file_get_contents($_REQUEST["scriptUrl"]));
?>
```

If you use this approach, you just have to send the script url you are calling the users' remote server as a parameter of scriptUrl.
Hope that helps!